# How does one show that $S_1=S_2$ and has the closed form of $1?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, gamma-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

Consider these sum

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\gamma^k\left(n-\Gamma\left({k\over n}\right)\right)^{-k}=S_1$$
>   and 
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-\gamma)^{1+k}\left(n-\Gamma\left({k\over n}\right)\right)^{-k}=S_2$$
>   Where $\gamma$ is [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html)

How does one show that $S_1=S_2$ and has the closed form of $\color{red}1?$

Comment: The Laurent series of $\Gamma(x)$ in a neighbourhood of $x=0$ is given by
$$ \Gamma(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\gamma+\frac{\zeta(2)+\gamma^2}{2}x+O(x^2)\tag{1} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the $\Gamma$ function has a simple pole at $z=0$, the behavior of $n-\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$ for $k\in[1,n]$ is pretty simple to understand. We have
$$ n-\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\gamma-\frac{1}{2n}\left(\zeta(2)+\gamma^2\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) $$
while for $k\geq 2$ we have
$$ \left(n-\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)^{-k} =O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
uniformly with respect to $k$. It follows that

> $$ S_1 = \color{red}{1},\qquad S_2 = \color{red}{\gamma} $$

since the only contribute that really matters is the contribute given by $k=1$.

Comment: I did a mistake on $(2)$ should be $(-\gamma)^k$. Thanks @Jack D'Aurizio